# Debugging Eclipse upstream plugins

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-pde

I got the source for Eclipse upstream plugins (that is, provided by the Eclipse Foundation) from the CVS and imported one of them to Eclipse PDE (in this case, `org.eclipse.core.runtime`). That did succeed, since the sources have the necessary metadata for PDE. I placed a few breakpoints and tried to launch it from the IDE with debugging, supposing that this would launch a new copy of an IDE so that the newly-built plugin would replace whatever would otherwise be loaded. This way I could debug Eclipse internals. However, it did not turn out this way. Building the plugin actually failed with literally thousands of errors.
So, should Eclipse source be buildable in this way? If there is a better way to do this, I am open to ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, it is expected that you checkout the plugin and be able to start hacking on it immediately and launch the new version... with one requirement: your target platform must match the the plugin's version. So, if you checked out the latest version, you need to have very recent nightly or integration build set up as Target Platform. If the plugin is from an older version (say 3.6 or 3.5), you'll need to set up the respective version.

The easiest way to setup your target platform is to download the corresponding build, extract it somewhere and then add the installation in the target platform (`Window -> Preferences -> Plug-in Development -> Target Platform`). *Hint: add it as Installation location.*

Comment: This is correct and this is how we work with Eclipse PDE itself :)

Comment: Now it should have the corresponding version, however, it still does not work, complaining about access restrictions in rt.jar. Much better, anyway. Compiling a plugin cannot need an exact matching version, otherwise a bootstrap problem would occur for every version. Doesn't the metadata have lists of dependencies and their respective versions, and the builder should notice if the versions are too far away?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a product based off the platform that you are launching from Eclipse, and you want to set breakpoints in platform code, you may be better off installing the Eclipse SDK.

Help -> Install New Software -> Pick the Eclipse Project Updates site. Choose the Eclipse SDK. This includes the source bundles for the platform.

You can either set a breakpoint by just Ctrl-Click'ing on the class that you want to debug and looking for the relevant spot, or Ctrl-Shift-T to open the type directly.

If you're just a downstream consumer of the platform, this is much easier than trying to get the versions to match.